# How to return a boolean in javascript to do form action

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have the following issue:

I have a foreach within a form, within this form I have a number type input that receives various data depending on the result of the query in the DB (normally they give results of 3 to 4 data) I have the code structured as follows :

```
<form autocomplete="off" action="somewhere.php" method="post" onsubmit="return validator();">
        <?php
    foreach($data["users"] as $dato){
        $pco_user= $dato["pco_user"];
        ?> <p class="card-text"><strong><?php echo $pco_user; ?></strong></p>
        <label>Number:</label>
        <input type="number" name="votation[]" class="votation"></input><?php
        }
        ?>
        <button type="submit" id="submit3" name="button1" class="btn btn-secondary" value="Save" type="button">Save</button>
    </form>
```

In the form tag I have the following code for onsubmit:

```
<script>
function validator()
{
const controls=document.querySelectorAll('.votation');
let ids=[];
controls.forEach(function(control)
    {
    event.preventDefault();
      if(ids.includes(control.value))
      {
        alert('Duplicate values');
        return true;
      }
      ids.push(control.value);
      return false;
    });
    
}
</script>
```

Basically what I am achieving at this moment is that the data that is being inserted is read before redirecting to the action of the form reading if there are equal values, but I cannot get that in the event that there are no equal values, I can redirect without problems, Any solution or can you tell me where I'm wrong?

Comment: Why is event.preventDefault(); inside the foreach loop?

Comment: Can you rephrase what is not working? I just plugged your code into CodePen and it correctly alerts if a duplicate is present.

Comment: @RyanDantzler hello , when i insert the values in the input fields , that do the confirmation if exist equal values to return false and dont do the action form, the problems is when i put different values (not equal) and the action do anything

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent form submission by using `event.preventDefault()` but if the onsubmit function is assigned inline then the `event` must be passed to the function as a parameter.

You can use [Array.every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) to find duplicates as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32122760/5818106).

```
<form action="script.php" method="post" onsubmit="validator(event)">
  <input type="number" class="votation">
  <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>

<script>
function validator(event) {
  // get all control input values
  const values = document.querySelectorAll('.votation').map(control => control.value);
  
  // check if there are any duplicates
  if (!values.every((element, index, array) => array.indexOf(element) === index) {
    alert("Duplicate values found");

    // prevent form submission
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your input! but when I try to run the example that you gave me in this case, when entering the same values, it redirects me in the same way and no alert appears

Answer (score -1):

Well, seeing your php HTML code you created a close tag for for `<input>`. HTML `<input>` tag does not have close tag.
Read more from [this](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp)

Comment: It's true, OP's code is not html valid, but that doesn't prevent JavaScript from being correctly executed. This does not solve OP's question.